# CSS font-family property IDE (PHPStorm) warning

Tags: css, fonts, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 8.0.3 and in my CSS file I get warning for `font-family` rule.

> This inspection verifies that the CSS font-family property contains a
>   generic font name as a fallback alternative.

I added the font as follows:

```
.my_text {
    font-family: 'DINPro-Medium';
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINPro-Medium';
    src: url(font/DINPro-Medium.eot);
    src: url(font/DINPro-Medium.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(font/DINPro-Medium.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(font/DINPro-Medium.woff) format('woff'),
    url(font/DINPro-Medium.svg#DINPro-Medium) format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I can not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It is recommended to add generic font families as a fallback while using a custom font.

Eg. `font-family: 'DINPro-Medium', serif;`

If the browser fails to load files for your custom font, it will use generic `serif` font.

Comment: We have this warning a lot for `FontAwesome`- here sans does not make so much sense - what do you think?

Comment: @Alex I think it doesn't make that much sense to have a generic fallback for an icon font, just ignore the warning.

Comment: @halfzebra But I want the warning bar clean :)

Comment: @Alex You could use stylelint with the relevant rule enabled, which you can disable on a per-line basis, and that would make it safe to disable the inspection in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 5):

Uncheck this checkbox which will disable the check:

[image]

Settings → Editor → Inspections → CSS → Probable bugs → Missing generic font name

Answer (score -2):

Just add a comment before a code block:

```
// noinspection CssNoGenericFontName
.my_text {
    font-family: 'DINPro-Medium';
}
```

You can read about it:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspection-results

Comment: In your answers please provide some details and explanations and not just a link and a code snippet

Comment: The best way is to specify a fallback font: font-family: 'dosis', serif;